# On the relationship between Martin's Axiom, the countable chain condition and the Knaster property

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, forcing

We say that a poset $P$ has the Knaster property (or is Knaster) if every uncountable subset of $P$ contains an uncountable subset of pairwise compatible conditions.

Let $K$ denote the statement "every c.c.c. poset is Knaster" and let $P$ denote the statement "the product of $2$ c.c.c. posets is c.c.c.". Then we have $\mathsf{MA}_{\aleph_1}\implies K \implies P$.

What are good examples of models showing that the implications are not reversible? (or are they?)

This question [was reposted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345749/on-the-relationship-between-martins-axiom-the-countable-chain-condition-and-th)

Comment: If I recall correctly, whether $\mathsf{MA}_{\aleph_1}$ and $\mathsf{K}$ are equivalent is an open problem. It's also mentioned as a problem in "Forcing with a coherent souslin-tree" by Stevo

Comment: Thanks for the reference @NotMike, I guess my question now becomes "what is known about whether $P\implies K$" then

Comment: They are non-reversible. See Fremlin's book *Consequences of Martin's Axiom" for a whole in depth discussion. He doesn't discuss the models or iterated forcing etc., but gives references IIRC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I remember looking at the book when I first thought about this question, but I didn't find a clear answer (possibly because of the nonstandard terminology adopted by the author). If you could give a more precise reference to a result in Fremlin's book I would be very happy to accept it as an answer though